# Art: What is オブジェ and what is not?

Tags: words

Here is how [Wiktionary](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7) defines [オブジェ](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7) in the context of art:

> 表現の対象となるもの、前衛美術では，幻想的効果のために取り入れられる物体。

My very hesitant attempt at a translation:

> It depends on the represented target, but in avant-garde art it is an object that has been transformed in order to produce an illusionary effect.

1. Could you improve my translation of the Wiktionary definition?
2. Is the result a good definition of オブジェ?

Comment: I see little reason not to use the existing definition in the English language for the original French word transparently referred to by the Japanese: [objet d'art](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objet%20d'art).

Comment: @Dave: objet d'art is broader than オブジェ. A commode Louis XV can be an objet d'art but not an オブジェ, as far as I understand.

Comment: "オブジェ  (n) objet d'art (fre:), item of artwork" according to EDICT, which is not always the most reliable source, but makes reasonable sense here.

Comment: in terms of the transformative power of avant garde art i think illusory is the wrong word to use here. 
i think this def. is referring to something like duchamp's urinal, where because of the artist's intervention the object takes on heretofore unknown or unseen power and meaning. however, in japanese, i heard this term used just like "sculpture". as in "my house is right across the street from that big sculpture"- i remember they used  オブジェ in that sentence, free from any mystical pretense.

Comment: perhaps here "visionary" would be a better trans of 幻想的. though visionary doesnt fit well w the sentence

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot yadokari! Do you think Wiktionary's definition could be improved? It is the dictionary anyone can improve, after all :-)

Comment: If you look at the [Daijirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7&enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss) def, it includes both `幻想的` and `象徴的` to describe it.

Comment: 象徴的 definitely would make sense. @raoul my jp is not good enough to adequately critique the original sentence, sorry :(

Comment: `幻想的` can be wondrous/fantasy/fantastical/visionary etc. I don't think `表現の対象となるもの` means "It depends on the represented target", "amounts to a subject of representation/expression" possibly. I don't know how to translate `取り入れられる物体`. "an assimilated/incorporated physical object"? "a physical object is incorporated"? I'm thinking the former but really don't know :( Having another try anyway, "Amounts to a subject of representation. When used in the context of avant-garde art, it's an assimilated physical object for the sake of a [visionary] effect."

Comment: i agree w cypher about the use of "represented target" being somewhat off . I made an attempt at a different trans yesterday but my browser crashed and i was unable to post it. if i have time again today i will make another attempt. I am a artist so I should learn these kind of terms.

Comment: i'm having trouble with
表現の対象となるもの
i see how you got target but I don't see how you got "it depends."
idk the ins and outs of all the meanings となるもの can have.

Comment: @yadokari I was mistaken for "it depends", in my confusion I somehow read となる as による.

Comment: As an agent of expression,  an object can be used in avant-garde art as a means to a visionary end.
i made
表現の対象となるもの As an agent of expression
though i don't think this is close enough.
i still don't understand 表現の対象となるもの
and i dont like that i used "as a" with "as an"

Comment: In a much simpler sense, wouldn't it be appropriate to refer "a means to a visionary end" be to the end result of a creative piece? The amalgamation of feeling and expression by the artist, the (final/completed) product itself, the 作品/work (of art)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another, (but similar,) approach... but combining both possible definitions of "objet" in the original context:

> 表現の対象となるもの、前衛美術では，幻想的効果のために取り入れられる物体。
>
> An expression transformed into an object
>   (used to surreal effect, in avant-garde art.)

*Note: "surreal" is used here to demonstrate a different approach for that part of the translation, though, something having to do more with the word "illusion" would probably be more accurate.*

Also, (and as already noted in the comments on the question,) this part: `It depends on the represented target,` doesn't seem to be in the original writing.

As long as the definition fits with the definition of ["objet" in French](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objet), the translation into English should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

> A target of depiction. In avant-garde art, an object introduced to create an illusory effect.

This might not be the best translation, but it avoids the pitfalls that others seem to have fallen into.

The first comma is a listing comma separating two definitions of the word.

[となるもの](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE) doesn't have much meaning, except for maybe taking an fairly abstract word (対象) and explicitly creating an instance of it.

幻想的 I find hard to translate, since I feel it's somewhere between "dreamy" and "illusory", both of which have slightly different connotations in English.